# Memory profiling with automation testing?

Tags: white-framework, memory-profiling, dotmemory

Currently adding some automation testing to our UI framework, and I was wondering if there was any way to perform some kind of memory profiling at the same time.

e.g. rather than having white start our application, have it start dotmemory (or another memory diagnostics tool) get a snapshot and then begin performing the automation tests.

I know this wouldn't track down memory leaks as such, but we could use it as an indicator if there's a spike in memory somewhere.

If anyone knows of a way to kick this off it would be very helpful, even if we had to use visual studios built in memory profiler rather than dot memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but managed to find this while googling around.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory-unit/2.3/Introduction.html

Still getting to grips with making it work, but seems promising.

Comment: May I ask you to create a ticket on [dotMemory Unit issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DMU) and describe what problems have you experienced and what improvements do you need?